# OKVideo: Controlling Video Playback with Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, jquery-plugins, youtube-api

Plugin Reference: http://okfoc.us/okvideo/  |  https://github.com/okfocus/okvideo

Hey Guys,

I've been trying to get my links to control which video plays with the OKVideo plugin but for some reason it doesn't work. I've tried a myriad of different method with no success.

To activate the plugin, you use:

```
$(function(){
    $.okvideo({                         
        source: 'BHE8Yre3Ex8',
    }) 
});
```

I've added some links that store the YouTube video ID as an attribute. When the user clicks the link, the video should stop playing the current video and begin playing the next selected one.

Also, I'm not trying to have the video play automatically (on page load)–only on a video selection. I've looked into the code but the options don't seem to work.

I've stripped my code and placed the core of it into jsfiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/mikemiketm09/rd4fL/

FYI: It did say you can use YouTube API with the plugin.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.